# Install Ruby 1.8 documentation?

Tags: ruby

My Ubuntu 12.04 already have ruby 1.8 installed, but I can't find a way to install documentation for `ri` , tried with libcommandline-ruby-doc package but it seems it's not it?

Answer (score 1):

You can install `ri` (Ruby Information at your fingertips) for ruby 1.8 with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ri1.8
```